# dynamic list of radiobuttons in angular

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular6

I have a list of radiobuttons that are not a part of a form. I would like to set to true just one of them, according to a value.

Then, when another one is clicked, all the others are set to false, except the clicked one.

The radiobuttons list is dynamic, generated by a `ngFor`,

I have something like

```
<div *ngFor='let item of array;let i = index'>                    
   <input type="radio" [checked]=false (click)='radioChecked(item.id,i)' > <input type="text" value='{{item.name}}' >  <button type="button" >save</button>                    
 </div>  

ngOnInit() {  
  this.myService.getNumber(id).subscribe((data) =>{  
  //when the page loads, set one of radiobuttons to true
  //somehow get the id and set to true, no standard is, since dynamic list
  radioId.value = true;
  })
}

radioChecked(id, i){
  //turn all the others to false, except this one
}
```

Since this is not in a form and there is no standard rows, so I can have an id, how can I do this? I  use angular 6

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

selected property should be part of the item object in an array.

**Template:**

```
    <div *ngFor='let item of array;let i = index'>                    
       <input type="radio" [checked]="item.selected" (change)='radioChecked(item.id,i)' > 
        <input type="text" value='{{item.name}}'/>  
        <button type="button">save</button>                    
     </div>
```

**Component:**

```
 radioChecked(id, i){
  array.forEach(item=>{
    if(item.id !== id){ 
       item.selected = false;
    }else{
       item.selected = true;
    } 
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh. I also dont see any other solution except putting `item.selected` in the object

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the correct answer is to use `(click)` not `(change)`